# ¿Cómo selecciono los ficheros que tienen uno o dos dígitos en su nombre?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

¿Cómo copio o muevo ficheros que tengan un dígito mayor al 9 en el nombre?

Es decir tengo file1.txt, file2.txt ... hasta el file20.txt

¿Cómo puedo copiar todos del tirón a una otra carpeta? Sé que con el comando:

```
cp file[0-9].txt
```

Pero me sirve para los 9 primeros, no con los demás.

si quisera user el mv igual

Como decir que copie de tal numero hacia adelante, he probado el `{1,20}` y no funciona.

por ejemplo

```
cp file[1-hacia delante].txt  /ruta/carpeta
```

o algo parecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar globbing para coger todos los ficheros cuyo nombre se componga de "file" seguido de 1 o más dígitos:

```
ls file+([0-9]).txt
```

Con `+([0-9])` especificamos que debe aparecer `[0-9]` una o muchas veces.

También puedes brace expansion `{inicio..final}` para esto:

```
ls file{1..20}.txt
```

La diferencia es que en este caso la expresión se expandirá a `file1.txt file2.txt ... file20.txt`, por lo que si alguno no existe dará error.